# How can i create directory and file recursively

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am creating a static site generator and using **fs module** for reading and writing files.

my question is how can I write new file in an non existing folder

for example:
**my root directory look like this**

[image]

and I want to create new file reclusively in a public directory that dose not exist.

**My code is this**

```
let list = [
"D:/test/public/index.html", 
"D:/test/public/test/test.html", 
"D:/test/public/test/newtst/anothertest.html"
]

list.forEach(filePath =>{
   fs.writeFileSync(filePath, content)
});
```

**but this code throw's an error:**

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:/test/public/index.html'
```

Thankyou.

Comment: [`fs.mkdir()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_options_callback)

Comment: You can use the `recursive` option to make the directories recursively.